# How can I create yearly folders to all my subfolders on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, folder

So currently my SharePoint library looks like this:

- A

  - Abel Henry

    - 2022-23
    - 2023-24
  - Agnes Carl

    - 2022-23
    - 2023-24
  - Azreal James

    - 2022-23
    - 2023-24
- B

  - Barry James

    - (same as in A)
  - Benita Henry

    - (continued)
  - (continued)
- (continued)

And I need to add a folder named "2024-25" to all the individuals folders, this folder would be on the same level as the "2023-24" level.

I have had a look at Power Automate but am confused, any help would be great. Thanks in advance.